# How to design API in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC controller but I'm not sure that it is a good or bad design. As far as I know, api versioning is missing but apart from that I implemented Swagger for documentation and added SpringSecurity and tried to follow YARAS(Yet Another RESTful API Standard) to build it but I need another eye on that to comment it.

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class XGameController implements GameController {

    private final GameService gameService;

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "game";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/games", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String initializeGame(Model model) {
        log.info("New XGame is initializing...");
        Game game = new Game();
        game = gameService.initializeGame(game.getId());

        try {
            model.addAttribute("game", mapper.writeValueAsString(game));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        log.info("New XGame is initialized successfully!");
        return "game";
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/games/{gameId}", method= RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody Game play(@PathVariable("gameId") String gameId,
                                   @RequestParam Integer pitNumber,
                                   @RequestParam String action) {
        log.info("Sowing stone is triggered...");
        return gameService.executeGameRules(UUID.fromString(gameId), pitNumber);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/403", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String error403() {
        return "/error/403";
    }

}
```

My swagger snapshot;

[image]

Comment: You should take this question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for better answer

Comment: if you post on Code Review please read the help center pages like [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  - the expectations are slightly different there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make some changes.

1. In `/games/{gameId}` I would use `PATCH` instead of `PUT`. The reason is that `PUT` is intended to completely replace the resource (in your case, the `Game`). This does not seem to be what you are doing in this endpoint. `PATCH` is intended to partially update a resource, which seems much more suited to what you are doing here.
2. Still in `/games/{gameId}` I would use the request body to provide the needed data instead of query parameters. It simply doesn't seem right. Query parameters are way more suited to `GET` requests than to `POST`, `PUT` or `PATCH`.
3. I would rename `/403` to something else that actually gives some context about what `403` is. Having said this, I would go with `/error-pages/403`. Additionally, I would also consider removing this endpoint from the swagger specification.

Other than this, it seems fine to me.

Comment: Why is there a `/403` at all? 403 is a _status_, not a URL.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but it seems to be the way to get the 403 error page. But still, it is at least debatable.

Comment: Would it be good to use @RequestBody and giving the whole model as a parameter? Wouldn't it make the model more vulnerable?

Answer (score 1):

Some advices :

1. Use a path that represents the context or the idea of your `controller` and you can add the `version`

   `@RequestMapping("/V1/xgame")`
2. Use specialized annotations such as : `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping` etc...
3. For `/403` use a meaning full name such as `/errors`
4. Use custom message that you will return to the users. For that you need a [ControllerAdvice](https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f).
5. Google on [patterns and best practices](https://dzone.com/articles/a-look-at-rest-api-design-patterns) Rest API design
6. Read some [books](https://bookauthority.org/books/new-api-design-books) for better undertanding.

Comment: Is this design too bad for the user to read some books? I mean, reading book is not a bad thing at all but does he need it to improve himself in case of this design approach?

Comment: Reading books is the base of every learning process. It is obvious to read books and good books.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, instead of **@RequestMapping** use a specific Mapping(Get, Post,etc.) and the use of type of mapping is up to you which you find more particular to the cause of using it
2. if you are redirecting from a page to homepage try to use return "**redirect**:"*/url*"" instead of just returning HTML file directly.
3. Rename your method for error, RequestMapping value to some more reasonable name.
4. instead of using **return "/error/403"**
   use **return "redirect:/error/403"**